# c++ publicly inherited class member cannot be used as default argument

Tags: c++, inheritance, arguments, default

A schematic of my problem...

```
class A
{
public:
    // etc.
protected:
    uint num;
};

class B : public A
{
public: 
    void foo(uint x = num); //bad
};
```

gives this error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘A::num’
error: from this location
```

Why does this happen, and what can I do to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this happens (based on the complaint about non-staticness) because there is no `this` pointer for it to use to know *which* instance of B it should get `num` from.

The Microsoft compiler (at least) allows you to specify an expression, but not a non-static member.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1dbzf09(VS.80).aspx):

> The expressions used for default
>   arguments are often constant
>   expressions, but this is not a
>   requirement. The expression can
>   combine functions that are visible in
>   the current scope, constant
>   expressions, and global variables. The
>   expression cannot contain local
>   variables or non-static class-member
>   variables.

Work-arounds for this are numerous and others have pointed out a few.  Here's one more which you may or may not like:

```
void foo(uint* x = NULL) {
  uint y = (x == NULL ? num : *x);
  // use y...
}
```

Comment: the workaround I used was assigning the default to UINT_MAX instead of NULL, but that caused conflicts elsewhere.  i just overloaded foo() instead.  thanks for the "this" explanation.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: No suspicion needed, its simply illegal to refer to non-static members in default arguments (except for pointers to members and class member access expressions).

Comment: Not just Microsoft. The standard allows expressions, but it forbids non-static members in 8.3.6/9: "Similarly, a nonstatic member shall not be used in a default argument expression, even if it is not evaluated, unless it appears as the id-expression of a class member access expression (5.2.5) or unless it is used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1)."

Comment: Oh good.  I didn't have time to go try to find the standard.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use overloading instead of default arguments.

```
class A
{
public:
    // etc.
protected:
    uint num;
};

class B : public A
{
public: 
    void foo(uint x);
    void foo() { foo( num ); }
};
```

Comment: thanks... this is the obvious solution but for some reason it skipped my mind. 
(the //bad comment in the solution is no longer needed, it's just from my question code)

Answer (score 1):

you can create 2 foos

foo()  //use num internally

foo(int x) //use x