# I want to use a non-static object variable as a default method argument

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ publicly inherited class member cannot be used as default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159538/c-publicly-inherited-class-member-cannot-be-used-as-default-argument)
>   [Nonstatic member as a default argument of a nonstatic member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539406/nonstatic-member-as-a-default-argument-of-a-nonstatic-member-function)

```
LinkedInteger accessElement(int index, LinkedInteger *startElement=&DataArray[0]){ // Starting at *startElement*, returns the element which is at the index of *startElement+index

    LinkedInteger NullElement;
    if (index<0){
        cout << "Index degeri sifirdan buyuk olmalidir" << endl;
        NullElement.value=0;
        NullElement.nextPtr=0;
        return NullElement;
    }       
    for (int i=0; i<index; i++){
        if (startElement->nextPtr == NULL){ // Last elements index is null.
            cout << " Erismeye calistiginiz eleman dizi sinirlarinin disindadir " << endl;
            NullElement.value=0;
            NullElement.nextPtr=0;
            return NullElement;}
        else {
            startElement=startElement->nextPtr;
        }
    }
    return *startElement; 
}
```

This is a method in implementation of Linked Lists in c++, which simply lets access to lists elements
I want to give the header as a default argument (which is indeed DataArray[0]).
It fails because of the error "invalid use of non-static data member".

```
this->&DataArray[0]
```

also fails because of "this may not be used in this context" What should I do?

Also there are some issues with the context of the code. Please ignore them.

Comment: You could use the singleton pattern maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an overload:

```
LinkedInteger accessElement(int index){
  return accessElement(index, &DataArray[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
// 0 or NULL; your preference

LinkedInteger accessElement(int index, LinkedInteger *startElement = 0)
{
   if (startElement == 0)
       startElement = &DataArray[0];  // or just startElement = DataArray;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I like the overload answer better. But this does show one way you can get around the specific limitation about what can and cannot be used as an initializer for a default argument.

Answer (score -1):

Default values for arguments have to be statically known. You cannot use a runtime value as default argument.

The latter fails because it's not a valid syntax and makes no sense pretty much.

Comment: It is wrong >> "*Default values for arguments have to be statically known*".

Comment: @Nawaz, hm it appears you're right; well, I guess it has to be a global at least, then.

Comment: it could be a function call as well.

Comment: Indeed it could; but that's pretty much because C++ allows you to initialize global variables from function calls.